# OracleAS 10g aborts request when downloading big excel file

Tags: java, excel, servlets, oas

I am facing a problem with a servlet that generates a big excel file created with POI.
This servlet executes a code similar to this:

```
    // (...)
    // set headers and names
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
        + fileName + ".xlsx");

    workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(flushLimit);
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // add rows and cell to excel file
            //(...) about 3000000 rows
        }

        logger.info("Writing and closing to temp file");
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
        logger.info("Dispose Workbook");
        workbook.dispose();
        logger.info("Closing fileOutputStream");
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileOutputStream);

        logger.info("Passing file to servlet outputstream");
        fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(tempFileOutput);

        IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, response.getOutputStream());

        logger.info("Closing fileInputStream");
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileInputStream);
        // delete temporal file
        try {
            tempFileOutput.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error trying to delete file");
        }

        // close servlet
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
```

When servlet takes more than 10 minutes to generate the report and the file sizes is about 100mb it sometimes shows a web saying Internal problem(with no more information) or in other cases the page remains loading.
Despite, the excel file is generated correctly but the transmission was cancelled.

Is there a configuration prevent OAS aborts the connection?

---

Comment: This might be a request timeout issue.

Comment: How can i configure that? i have tried increasing the Timeout in Apache httpd.conf but it does not work

Comment: Internal problems usually are logged.  Also you can wrap your code in a try-catch(Throwable t) so you can inspect this yourself.  Considered attaching a debugger?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, the code doesn't throw any exception. in most of the tries it just get stuck while it is writing bytes in output stream.

Comment: Be very careful with writing to the filesystem.  This makes you vendor dependent.  Any reason you cannot use workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()) and avoid using the file system?

Comment: Initially I was writing on outputStream, then when the problem appear, I moved it to a file in order to check if file is generated. Both cases I have the same issue. It's like connection between IExplorer and OAS has broken, and then OAS get stuck while writing on the outputStream. :-(

Comment: It might very well be Internet Explorer closing the connection prematurely (if it takes more than X seconds or the output comes too slowly).  Could you please try with Firefox and Chrome and see if you can replicate the problem?

Comment: Yes, I can replicate the problem in Chrome. I have replaced:
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); 
instead of  
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
Apparently, this fixes the problem, but I am making more testing. It is really weird